# D3 - positioning edges is throwing NaN errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nan

Based on the guide from Stephen Thomas https://github.com/sathomas/jsDataV.is-source/tree/master/ch7/force, I have tried to make a d3 force layout graph.

However I am stuck on an error that I do not know the origin of and how to tackle it.

Given the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Bx0qe8DNEsnFgLhkxbfS?p=preview this snippet is causing

```
 var positionEdge = function(edge, nodes) {
        edge.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
    };
```

Many errors e.g. Error: Invalid value for  attribute y2="NaN"

I build my edges array as following, but to fully be able to reproduce the problem please use the plunker link:

```
 var edges = [];
        links.forEach(function(srcLink){
            var targetNodeId;
            var targetNodeName;
            var sourceNodeId;
            var sourceNodeName;

            nodes.forEach(function(srcNode){
              if(srcNode.label === srcLink.source){
                  sourceNodeId = srcNode.id;
                  sourceNodeName = srcNode.label;
              } else if(srcNode.label === srcLink.target){
                  targetNodeId = srcNode.id;
                  targetNodeName = srcNode.label;
              }
            })
            edges.push({
                "id": "From_" + sourceNodeName + "_To_" + targetNodeName,
                "target": targetNodeId,
                "source": sourceNodeId
            });
        })

        // remove duplicate edges
        var arr = {};
        for ( var i=0, len=edges.length; i < len; i++ )
            arr[edges[i]['id']] = edges[i];

        edges = new Array();
        for ( var key in arr )
            edges.push(arr[key]);
```

**What is causing all the NaN errors being thrown when the positionEdge function is called?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `source` and `target` fields in your edges are node ids, rather than objects. You have two solutions:

- use objects:

  ```
     edges.push({
          "id": "From_" + sourceNodeName + "_To_" + targetNodeName,
          "target": nodes[targetNodeId],
          "source": nodes[sourceNodeId]
      });
  ```

or

- use indices (bad idea, see edit note below)

  ```
  var positionEdge = function(edge, nodes) {
      edge.attr("x1", function(d) { return nodes[d.source].x; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return nodes[d.source].y; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return nodes[d.target].x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return nodes[d.target].y; });
  };
  ```

The standard in `d3` is to use the first option, but there might be other edits to bring to your code if you go for it. With the second option, you'll be stuck with using nodes[d.source] and nodes[d.target] every time you need an edge endpoint.

---

**Edit**: Actually, the `force` layout automatically converts index-based edges into object-based. So unless you use two different arrays for edges, you need to go for the first option.

Comment: Thank you very much laurent. I have opted to go for the 2nd option you gave me because using the first one results in exactly the same errors (probably due the other edits needed which you noted). **With the second option I am no longer seeing the error that I opened the topic for**. Hence, I will mark your answer as the anser to my question. However, if you would be willing to have a look at the renewed plunker example, I would really appreciate that. I am getting the `Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"` error. http://plnkr.co/edit/Bx0qe8DNEsnFgLhkxbfS?p=preview

Comment: @Sander_M: I completely forgot that using the first option was not only the standard, but actually enforced by `d3.force` (see edit). Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: I am sad to hear that option 2 is not a valid one ;) I am going take your advise and use objects as target and source. Probably means I have to start all over again. Very good for my learning curve, I am really loving data visualization with D3. Even tho it feels more complex than for example sigma.js, it also provides so many more options and possibilities. Thanks for clearing things up and the edit!